# Error al cargar texturas en Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

Tengo en Codesandbox el código de un visor para .gltf y lo pase a  mi computadora locamente, en teoría debería de ser los mismo. Esto lo hago para ver modelos mas grades y hacer otras pruebas.

Dejo el link de mi sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/visor-gltf-simple-t7zwfw

Localmente tengo un error al cargar las texturas de mi modelo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberia de usar un textureLoader para esta textura
Porque no me muestra este error en sandbox

Comment: Dos cosas: 1) Las preguntas en este sitio han de ser autocontenidas para ser válidas.  Si dejas el código en un enlace externo, eso no asegura que siempre estará allí, y la pregunta podria perder su contexto. El código va en la pregunta mediante un ejemplo (no hace falta todo el código, solo lo necesario para reproducir  el error). Mírate [example].  2) Ese error te dice que no encuentra un archivo, que quizas en el sandbox si que esté bien instalado eso que usas, pero en tu propio pc parece que no, y de ahi el error. Revisa cómo se instala y agrega los archivos que te falten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Llegue a la conclusión que al archivo necesario para reproducir un modelo en formato GLTF debes de tener todas las texturas colocadas en la carpeta correspondiente o usar el archivo glb también admitido por Three.js